# Prevent access to URL with htaccess with condition

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an url :

```
https://abc.sitetest.com/images/abc/img.jpg
```

We read the subdomain from url which is `abc`. Using htaccess, we only allow the user to view abc and its subfolder. So if there's a folder `/images/cde/...` they can't view or read any file (not an image) in it.

It could be this but I'm not sure it's the way...

```
<Limit GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from abc.sitetest.com
</Limit>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to rephrase it with examples.

Comment: @anubhava I did. The first url is an example... We compare the subdomain `abc` and the folder `/images/abc` so we know it's a valid url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this back reference based rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.[^:]+:(?!.*?/\1/).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will allow:

```
https://abc.sitetest.com/images/abc/img.jpg
https://abc.sitetest.com/anything/abc/foo
```

but will block:

```
https://abc.sitetest.com/images/xyz/img.jpg
https://abc.sitetest.com/def/img.jpg
```